# No input file specified. after deleting the user

Tags: wordpress

I had 3 websites running wordpress. My intern deleted an account that manages the three websites. After deleting the accounts I seeing this error `No input file specified`. Is there anyway to fix this TREMENDOUS mistake?

Comment: If you manage backups regularly, then just restore most earlier version.

Comment: What if I don't have any backups? Can I just add the user and rewrite the settings pointing this to the new user? I have plesk managing this websites. Is this any good?